# How does Chrome find the function call stack, can I call it directly in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer

I want to get the function call stack in normal programming rather than exceptions(not new Error().stack).

For example, I already know that the function ***f*** is called when the  tag is clicked, and the source code of ***f*** is as follows:

```
    function f () {
        ...
        f1 (); // f1 is a custom function in another JavaScript file
        ...
    }
```

Now I have ***f*** handle and name of ***f1***, can I get ***f1*** in which file by calling some function in chrome or puppeteer and get its number of lines?

Comment: can you rephrase your question

Comment: As I understood it, he's basically looking for a while to get access to a stack trace which you can manually walk through.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to grab a hold of the normal stack which the browsers use directly (at least no standard way, and no way I've ever hard of). This is usually down inside of the guts of the native processing portion. The closest way would be `new Error().stack` which you already mentioned you don't like.

The only other way to add something to each function which would have it append itself to a stack that you maintain.

You could do this by creating some sort of wrapper function, something like this:

```
const stack = []; // somewhere in the global space

const wrapInStackReporter = realFunc => function () {
    stack.push({ func: realFunc, name: realFunc.name, arguments });
    realFunc.apply(this, arguments);
    stack.pop();
};
```

You could then use it like:

```
const someFunc = wrapInStackReporter(() => console.log('doing something'));
```

You would then have `stack` in the global space which would keep track of what is going on.

You could go one step further and automate the wrapping by having it recursively loop through all functions it can find (starting at the global space and going down from there) so you wouldn't have to manually wrap every function:

```
const wrapAll = (target) => {
    Object.keys(target).forEach(key => {
      if (typeof target[key] == "object" && !(target[key] instanceof Function)) {
        wrapAll(target[key]);
      } else if(target[key] instanceof Function) {
        target[key] = wrapInStackReporter(target[key]);
      }
    });
};

wrapAll(window || global); // window for browsers, global for Node
```

The code above should be close, but probably doesn't take into account all possible weirdness you'll run in to, but it gives you a general idea. You'd have to be careful about causing side effects and weird conditions as well (especially if you go with the auto-wrap approach).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I have found 2 ways to get the call stack:
(1)use `console.trace()` in Chrome console([link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3)), I am still looking for a way to get the output.
(2)use `arguments.callee.caller` in a function.